# If a is a non-zero real number and b is a positive real number and $2ba^4 + ba^3 + a^2 + ba + 2b = ka^2$, then the least possible value of $k$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Least possible value of $k$ is:

$2b + 1$

$2b - 1$

I wrote it in the form of dividing the LHS with $a^2$, and dividing each element with $a^2$, and writing down the summation of terms only to be equated with $k$.

But, I can't seem to get anywhere. Some help will surely be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: write it in terms of $c = a+ 1/a$, using that $a^2+1/a^2=c^2-2$.

Comment: @dxiv But how can we even write it in that form?

Comment: After "*dividing the LHS with $a^2$, and dividing each element with $a^2$, and writing down the summation*" you get $\,2b(a^2+1/a^2)+b(a+1/a)+1-k=0\,$ where the LHS is a quadratic in $\,c=a+1/a\,$.